# How can I save user data?

Tags: java, android, history

Currently I am building a QR code scanning app, but a feature I want to add is when after they scan the barcode, the link will be saved for them to access later. Is there any way I can go about adding this feature? I assume I would have to use a database, what about implement ing it?

Thank you

Comment: Yes you need a database or shared preference to persist that data.

Comment: one of the easiest ways to use databases in Android is [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following operations:

Step 1. Select the applicable databases (Oracle, MySQL, Mongo)

Step 2. Build the environment based on the selected database

Step 3. Create a data table in the database (probably including the following fields, unique table ID, unique user ID, QR code link, etc.)

Step 4. Add a scaffold corresponding to the database in the application

Step 5. Configure data details in the application (database link, account, password, etc.)

Step 6. Add the corresponding database operation in the user's QR code scanning method

Step 7. Add a page to display the historical QR code link in the application